# sql/spark-sql: if statement syntax in a query

Tags: sql, join, apache-spark-sql

I am looking into some existing spark-sql codes, which trying two join to tables as below:

```
items_t1_t2 as (
    select *,
    if(id_t1 is not Null, True, False) as in_t1,
    if(id_t2 is not Null, True, False) as in_t2
    from item_t2 full join item_t1
    on id_t2 = id_t1)
```

I am wondering why there is three elements in the if parentheses? What does the if statement mean here and how it works here? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The outer parentheses are for what looks like a `common table expression`, basically a different way of writing a `subquery`.  The parentheses around the `if` statements are just seeing if those columns are `null` and returning `true` or `false` accordingly...

Answer (score 10):

The "IF" statement in Spark SQL (and in some other SQL dialects) has three clauses:

```
IF (condition_to_evaluate, result_if_true, result_if_false)
```

In this case, for instance, the expression:

```
IF(id_t1 IS NOT NULL, True, False) AS in_t1
```

Is logically equivalent to this one:

```
id_t1 IS NOT NULL AS in_t1
```

Or, to put it in another way: `in_t1` is just a flag saying "if id_t1 is not null" and the same goes for `in_t2` and `id_t2`.